# Does the CreateThread API in windows automatically spread threads across multiple cores?

Tags: c, windows, winapi

I have a question regarding the CreateThread API in windows (C/C++) that MSDN of the API doesn't explain.

If i use this API to create multiple threads that execute a function (all of them execute a common function), will Windows automatically spread these threads across different cores? specially if the function is CPU intensive?

Comment: Read official doc on Scheduling: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/procthread/scheduling and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/procthread/multiple-processors, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most operating systems internally treat processes and threads as a specialization of more general "tasks". By default tasks have no fixed association with particular cores. In general the OS will try to reschedule tasks on the same core in the short term, to aid with cache coherence, but will cycle them over all associated cored in the long term to distribute the thermal load.

It is however possible to limit the set of cores a given task may run on using the so called "CPU affinity mask", which can be set either at runtime using a system call, or as part of the executable binary at link time.

Comment: I think OP is specifically asking for how windows OS acts in this case, not other operating systems. Based on my knowledge the windows OS does spread threads across multiple cores in most cases, are you saying this is not true?

Comment: @Notoriouss: Well, did I tell anything different? Please read my answer again, carefully.